# JKR says that Hermione shouldn't have married Ron. Is this correct?

Tags: character-analysis, j-k-rowling, harry-potter

[In an interview](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/feb/02/jk-rowling-hermione-harry-ron-married), JKR says that Hermione would not have married Ron:

> She told the magazine: "I wrote the Hermione-Ron relationship as a
>   form of wish fulfilment. That's how it was conceived, really.
>
> "For reasons that have very little to do with literature and far more
>   to do with me clinging to the plot as I first imagined it, Hermione
>   ended up with Ron.
>
> "I know, I'm sorry, I can hear the rage and fury it might cause some
>   fans, but if I'm absolutely honest, distance has given me perspective
>   on that. It was a choice I made for very personal reasons, not for
>   reasons of credibility.
>
> "Am I breaking people's hearts by saying this? I hope not."
>
> The author said the duo would have likely needed relationship
>   counselling, while Watson herself also doubted the couple's potential
>   longevity.
>
> "I think there are fans out there who know that too and who wonder
>   whether Ron would have really been able to make her happy," Watson
>   told the Sunday Times.

Of course, in the books, Hermione does marry Ron and not Harry. So JKR's proclamation that Hermione would not marry Ron seems odd to say the least.

Based on what we know about the two characters, is this correct? Should JKR's word overrule the text of the books in this case?

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to Stack Exchange! As this is a speculative question, it would be greatly improved if you included some of your reasoning for why this might _not_ be the case. Is there something in the text that leads you to believe it is _not_ correct?

Comment: I never found the Hermione-Ron romance unbelievable, it's the Harry-Ginny romance that is weak and perfunctory.  Clearly, Harry should have ended up with Luna....

Comment: @ChrisSunami Why in the world should . . . actually, that kind of makes sense. Huh.

Comment: *“Hermione does marry Ron and not Harry”* — nowhere in the linked interview does Rowling compare those alternatives. (It's present only in the context set up by the article.) I see no reason why if she doesn't marry one she should marry the other! Rowling only says the Hermione-Ron relationship seems a weak one. This does not mean it's worse than the Hermione-Harry relationship. There are more than two men in the world, even in the Harry Potter world.

Comment: Take a look at this related question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59391/why-did-hermione-fall-in-love-with-ron

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133280/4918 , which quotes the same interview as you here, is also relevant.

Comment: Full interview of OP quotes here:  https://www.hypable.com/jk-rowling-ron-hermione-interview/

Answer (score 3):

Based on the textual evidence, I disagree with JKR. In HP4, when Hermione first appears in her ball gown, Harry merely says that "she didn't look like Hermione at all." It's merely implied and not stated that she looks better than usual. Also starting in HP4, Ron gets jealous of Krum and Hermione is annoyed at Ron for not understanding her feelings, which is why she sends that flock of birds to attack him.

On a structural level, Harry has always been the key connecting element of his group of friends, even beyond the fact that he's the focalizer of the narrative. He befriends Ron, then befriends Hermione (or at least she isn't annoyed at his stupidity), and only after the Halloween troll do Ron and Hermione become friendly. So it's more likely that Harry is friendzoned from the start, whereas Hermione's negative feelings toward Ron are later transformed into positive ones.

Finally, following along with Harry's POV, we never see him surprised at Hermione's romance with Ron. And given all that Harry has to deal with, I think it's better for Hermione not to be with him.

Comment: Interesting that you say that Harry is the narrator. I would say that it's in third person limited point of view, so he is not really the narrator, but we know what's happening only from his perspective.

Comment: You're right! My bad. I've changed it to say that Harry's the focalizer of the narrative.

Answer (score -1):

On a structural and autobiographical level JKR saw the reunion of the three friends as the perfect ending to an overall painful and exhausting series and there couldn't have been a better platform than the Weasley family for that. Hermione married Ron and Harry was married to Ginny Weasley as a part of that plan. Besides, Harry got the much awaited love of his parents in the form of Arthur and Molly Weasley. Hermione was accused for her non magical background, but the Weasley family is, from the start, shown to have a particular sentiment of love for the Muggle-borns despite themselves being pure-bloods. So marrying Ron to Hermione was not just by accident but by a proper design.